# Arraylist display selected listview to textview

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist

I'm just a noob in android. I've got this code from someone's blog.

He made a simple database query and populate an arraylist in listview.

How do I get a value from each selected item in listview to text view in new activity?

Here's the arraylist code:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> rowTable() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> fillArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
    Cursor cur;
    try {
        cur = db.query(TABLE_TEST, new String[] { ROW_ID, ROW_NAME,
                ROW_CLASS }, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        if (!cur.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                ArrayList<Object> fillList = new ArrayList<Object>();
                dataList.add(cur.getLong(0));
                dataList.add(cur.getString(1));
                dataList.add(cur.getString(2));

                dataArray.add(fillList);

            } while (cur.moveToNext());

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR DATABASE", e.toString());
    }
    return fillArray;
}
```

and here's the listview code.

```
private void getArrayList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getData = dtbase.rowTable();//
    name = new String[getData.size()];
    for (int x = 0; x < getData.size(); x++) {

        ArrayList<Object> getRow = getData.get(x);
        name[x] = getRow.get(1).toString();

    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> sName = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name);
    lv.setAdapter(sName);
}
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy to get the selected item

Here is the method you need to override.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
    ...
}
}
```

Then use the position argument to access the arraylist so you could display it in your textview.